# Distinct substring from nested select only if delimiter exists?

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

Here is the query I am using to parse certain pieces of a username from a field

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(UserName, CHARINDEX('^', UserName) + Len('^'),LEN(UserName) as un, 
FROM (
        SELECT TOP 10000 * 
        FROM SomeTable
        ORDER BY LocalDateTime DESC
)
```

The problem is that usernames which do not have a `^` are irrelevant and I do not want to include them.  How can I do this?  For instance, if I had the following data:

```
system1^name1
system2^name2
system3^name2
name3
```

I would receive these results:

```
name1
name2
```

**NOTE:** I do not want to modify the internal query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just add a condition in the subquery or the outer query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(UserName, CHARINDEX('^', UserName) + Len('^'), LEN(UserName) as un
FROM (SELECT TOP 10000 * 
      FROM SomeTable
      ORDER BY LocalDateTime DESC
     ) t
WHERE UserName LIKE '%^%'
```

Comment: Sorry, made an edit JUST before you posted. :(  (went ahead and upvoted anyway since yes, this would work)

Comment: @DevilsAdvocate . . . It can just as easily go in the outer query.

Comment: I feel pretty stupid.  Not that that's unusual.  Thanks :)